# Pygtk - How to center a window on a parent window border?

Tags: pygtk

How can I make a child widget (in this case other window, a popup one) popup attached to the border of the parent window? I know I can center it in the parent with: `gtk.Window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT)`, but how can I make it popup in the border?

Comment: You mean, the child window's border exactly below parent's border, but horizontally in the middle?

Comment: If yes, (And if you are using Gnome) I think new Metacity versions does exactly the same thing automatically (and even i don't think it could be changed)

Comment: Yeah, I want the child window's border exactly below parent's border, horizontally but alligned to the left, just like the dictionary applet from gnome panel. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...:P

I managed to solve it by using:

`(x, y) = parent.get_position()`

`y1 = y+50`

`child.move(x, y1)`